# Unselection of Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-flexi-radio-button, it's all working fine. But i have a dynamic data it displays in ListView. Once i have selected one option in ListView then the index value will be changed. After i have to select another option then the index value will be changed but the radio button will be in multiple selected mode.
This is module link:[enter link description here](https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-flexi-radio-button)
Here is my code:

```
onSelect(index, value){
  this.setState({
    index:index,
    value:value
  },()=>{
    this.setState({
      text:'Selected index:'+this.state.index+' , value: '+this.state.value
    })
  })
}

listRow(list, sectionID:number, rowID:number){
  var attributes=[];
  list.options.map((list,i)=>{
    attributes.push(
       <View style={styles.listOfAttributesView}>
        <View style={styles.dataRowAttributesView}>
         <RadioGroup
                onSelect = {(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}
                color={'black'}
                size={20}
                thickness ={2}>

                <RadioButton value={list} >
                  <Text>{list}</Text>
                </RadioButton>
              </RadioGroup>
              <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
       </View>
       </View>
     )
   })
  return(
    <View>
      {attributes}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Here is my screenshot:
[image]

Please give me suggestion.Thank you

Comment: *but the radio button will be in multiple selected mode.* Why not use a checkbox in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want single selection in this case.